# show low in stock products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

for my website, I need a page to display the low in stock products only, as same as choosing to display only top rated, sales, recent products.
I found a code to display the out of stock .. so I just replace "outofstock" value to "lowinstock", but that doesn't work, it shows all of the products

```
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
   
function bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {
 
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'outofstock',
         )
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );
    
   $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
    
   return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
 
}
```

Do you have any solutions for this??
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the product IDs and check if the amount in stock is lower than the low stock threshold but greater than zero (out of stock).

```
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
function bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );

    $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach ( $product_ids as $key => $product_id ) {
        if ( $product = wc_get_product( $product_id ) ) {

            $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $low_stock_amount = $product->get_low_stock_amount();

            if ( !empty( $stock ) && !empty( $low_stock_amount ) ) {
                if ( $stock > $low_stock_amount || $stock < 1 ) {
                    unset( $product_ids[$key] );
                }
            } else { //Not enough stock data
                unset( $product_ids[$key] );
            }

        }
    }
    $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
    return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this shows all of the products too, it doesn't filter the products to just "low in stock"

Comment: I tested this locally and works. Maybe your low stock threshold is set quite high?

Comment: no .. It is two only. I added this short code [out_of_stock_products] to one of my pages .. but as I said it returns all of the published products. Is there any specific setting configuration to do??

Comment: Make sure your cache is cleared and you are using the `[out_of_stock_products]` shortcode.